Some HTTP to HTTPS redirections were not done using Python Requests
When visiting http://www.google.com in a browser located in the US, it should be redirected to https://www.google.com. However, this does not appear to work when using Python Requests, as demonstrated in the code below.
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)

r = requests.get("https://google.com", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)

r = requests.get("http://google.com", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)

r = requests.get("http://github.com", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)

The output is:
https://www.google.com/
[]
http://www.google.com/
[]
https://www.google.com/
[<Response [301]>]
http://www.google.com/
[<Response [301]>]
https://github.com/
[<Response [301]>]

You can see that the second request was not redirected from HTTP to HTTPS using Python Requests, however, the redirection does occur in my Chromium browser. In contrast, the request made to http://github.com/ was responded with a redirection response, which was followed. Using Chromium's Developer Tools, I observed that the very first request made to http://www.google.com is already converted to https://www.google.com, which might be something only done by the browser but not Python Requests. An answer regarding HTTPS redirection on Super User suggests that this might be related to HSTS?
Therefore, I would like to know why Python Requests does not do HTTP to HTTPS redirection for certain websites, and how can I make such redirection work as if I am using a browser?
I am using Python 3.10.12, requests==2.32.3, and I am comparing it to Chromium 126.0.6478.126.

Google does not redirect for some agents, e.g. cURL, requests... You can try to add some headers to simulate a browser.

@KlausD. Thanks, your suggestion works. I copied the User-Agent value from my browser and passed it to requests and it works. http://www.google.com/ is now redirected to https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl. You are welcome to post an answer here. It would be even better if you can elaborate more on whether this is what happens in general (not just Google), why Google does this, and why non HTTP-to-HTTPS redirects work (my third and fourth request in code) but not HTTP to HTTPS.

Just wanted to note that the question is very interesting.
